# Display ACF on blog archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I need to display some extra information on the blog archive page, but can't code it in because other people must be able to edit the information.

I added some custom fields on this page, but can't display them on the actual page.
Any way to solve this?

**My code:**

```
<div class="save_the_date">
    <?php
    if( have_rows('actiedagen') ):
        while ( have_rows('actiedagen') ) : the_row();
            the_sub_field('actiedagen_titel');
            the_sub_field('actiedagen_datum');
            the_sub_field('actiedagen_locatie');
        endwhile;
    else :

    endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an options page for editing those fields:

```
if (function_exists('acf_add_options_page')) {

    acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'     => 'Theme General Settings',
        'menu_title'    => 'Theme Settings',
        'menu_slug'     => 'theme-general-settings',
        'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect'        => false
    ));
}
```

Then display this field group on this options page.

As to showing the values, you would need to add the second parameter "option" like this:

```
    <?php
    if( have_rows('actiedagen', 'option') ):
        while ( have_rows('actiedagen', 'option') ) : the_row();
            the_sub_field('actiedagen_titel'); // no need to add option here
            the_sub_field('actiedagen_datum');
            the_sub_field('actiedagen_locatie');
        endwhile;
    else :

    endif;
    ?>
```